# find two tables differences

Tags: sql, oracle

we have one Oracle sql like:

```
with temp1 as (
 select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from a 
), temp2 as (
   select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from b 
)
select *
from
(
( select * from temp1
minus
select * from temp2  )
union
( select * from temp2 
minus
select * from temp1  )
)
union
(SELECT * FROM temp1 T1
LEFT JOIN temp2 T2 ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
WHERE T1.col2 <> T2.col2 )
```

but it throws "ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns",

Could you please give some advice on it?

Comment: Why last union is used? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want to do.  However, this part returns 10 columns, not 5:

```
SELECT *
FROM temp1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     temp2 T2
     ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
```

So the number of columns are not the same.

List the columns explicitly -- with aliases -- for all subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Error you got is because of this:

```
with 
temp1 as (
  select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from a    --> TEMP1 has 5 columns
), 
temp2 as (
  select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from b    --> TEMP2 has 5 columns
)
select *
from
(
( select * from temp1                       --> TEMP1 MINUS TEMP2 has 5 columns  --> OK
minus
select * from temp2  )
union
( select * from temp2                       --> TEMP2 MINUS TEMP1 has 5 columns  --> OK
minus
select * from temp1  )
)
union
(SELECT * FROM temp1 T1                     --> TEMP1 JOIN TEMP2 has 10 columns  --> WRONG
LEFT JOIN temp2 T2 ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
WHERE T1.col2 <> T2.col2 )
```

If the last query (the "wrong" one) is rewritten as e.g. `select t1.* from ...`, it would work, but the question is whether this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Last query has 10 columns in select list and other queries have 5. Last query should be either t1.* Or t2.* Or anything custom but with 5 columns